# How to return a single value from a controler after an ajax request? Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am making an ajax call to a controler from a view like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=participate&amp;task=participate_request&amp;virtuemart_product_id=2&amp;virtuemart_category_id=5&amp;tmpl=component&amp;Itemid=101",
              data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
```

and in the controler
I have a task method declared like this

```
public function participate_request(){          
        echo 'test';
        return false;
    }
```

And I get this response

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="el-gr" lang="el-gr" >
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>offer_e_shop_1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//css/facebox.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//css/vmsite-ltr.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//js/jquery.noConflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//js/vmsite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//js/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets//js/vmprices.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
vmSiteurl = 'http://localhost/offer_e_shop_1/' ;
vmLang = ""
vmCartText = ' was added to your cart.' ;
vmCartError = 'There was an error while updating your cart.' ;
loadingImage = '/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets/images/facebox/loading.gif' ;
closeImage = '/offer_e_shop_1/components/com_virtuemart/assets/images/facebox/closelabel.png' ; 
Virtuemart.addtocart_popup = '0' ; 
faceboxHtml = '<div id="facebox" style="display:none;"><div class="popup"><div class="content"></div> <a href="#" class="close"></a></div></div>'  ;

  </script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/offer_e_shop_1/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/offer_e_shop_1/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/offer_e_shop_1/templates/mov_jean_cc_offer_e_shop_2/css/print.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="contentpane">

<div id="system-message-container">
</div>
 test
</body>
</html>
```

How can I return only the test value alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jexit(),exit() or add &format=raw in url string or use given code in controller function:

```
$app = &JFactory::getApplication();
$app->close()
```

Answer (score 1):

echo all your output text and just place a die(); after that

Comment: where did you have put that die(); statement.

Comment: in the function participate_request in the controler

Comment: but simply adding &format=raw on the request causes joomla to spit out only the returned value of the method in the controler

Comment: i think &format=raw only works if is it supported by that component.

i had done this kind of stuff many time by using die(); in my template file (file under tmpl folder).

make sure you have written die() before your return statement in that function

Comment: http://blog.joomlatools.eu/2008/01/joomla-15-generating-raw-ouput.html

"What happens is you are now telling the system to use a different output format called ‘raw’ instead of ‘html’ the default one. The system will load the JDocumentRAW output format to render the document and will only output whatever the component creates."
And it seems that it is also supported in joomla 2.5. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: not sure if i ma 100% correct but a per my knowledge to get raw output , your view should have view.raw.php along with view.html.php . same is the concept with format=feed. But as you are not dealing with the view part and outputting your content in controller task function,  try to put following lines at the start of your function 


$document = & JFactory::getDocument();
$document = & JDocument::getInstance('raw');

i had not tried it but someone had suggested it in the last response here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/joomla-dev-cms/-WDbOmvTNdc%5B1-25%5D

Comment: no it does not work, But! before I did something wrong, maybe I was tired or something, but die(); does work after all without passing the raw parameter, and sorry about that. I am 24 hours strait, working over my code.. probably my brain got died(); :P thanx

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add Jexit() at the end of your task & you will get rid of full html. You can use die() as well but why if there is Jexit(). 
        function edit()
        {
         // Your code
         Jexit(); 
        }

Answer (score 0):

found it.. in the end of the url string.. you need to attach &format=raw
So the request will be

```
jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=participate&amp;task=participate_request&amp;virtuemart_product_id=2&amp;virtuemart_category_id=5&amp;tmpl=component&amp;Itemid=101&format=raw",
              data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
```

! so easy after all.