# jQuery ajax - How to get text only when joomla component return?

Tags: jquery, joomla

How to get joomla2.5 component return only text when using jquery ajax?
Because now I get Full html. I try to add "&format=raw" but not work !
How to fix it ?

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php?option=com_test&task=edit",

  ......................
```

Comment: if you dont want extra html in your ajax response just output all your text and put die(); at the end of it. This link may give your some more detail
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926798/how-to-return-a-single-value-from-a-controler-after-an-ajax-request-joomla-2-5/11927996#11927996

Answer (score 1):

When I need to ouput some JSON I don't usually let the controller even go to the view.  I put the data I want into an object and pass it to this function:

```
function jsonOut($obj) {
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();

  JResponse::setHeader( 'Expires', 'Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT', true );    // Expires in the past
  JResponse::setHeader( 'Last-Modified', gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT', true ); // Always modified
  JResponse::setHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );

  echo json_encode($obj);
  $app->close();
}
```

No view required.  It just spits out the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add Jexit() at the end of your task & you will get rid of full html. You can use die() as well but why if there is Jexit(). Cheers.

```
    function edit()
    {
     // Your code
     Jexit(); 
    }
```